# How to show CICS Elements in z/OS COBOL V5.2 Listing

Tags: cobol, zos, cics

When compiling a z/OS COBOL V5.2 program with CICS, how can I get the CICS elements, such as DFHEIBLK and DFHCOMMAREA, to be shown in the source listing section and not only in the storage mapping section of the compile output?

Thanks for your help

Comment: You mean when using the compiler option CICS, the integrated processor, rather than a pre-processor? I think there may be a Request For Enhancement (RFE) out on this, or something related to improving the listing output. The RFE site is on Developerworks, you'll need an IBM ID, which means you set up an account (free) with your email address and a password, and then you can vote on, comment on, or submit your own, RFEs.

Comment: Yes, using the integrated co-processor. So you're saying that there isn't a compiler option or such that controls if they are included in the listing or not? That for now it's a "feature" that they are **not** included?

Comment: I may not agree with your interpretation, but yes. They are actually in the output, as you've already mentioned, just not also in the place where you would previously have seen them, Other than familiarity, does this cause you a particular problem?

Comment: Not a specific problem, but it is somewhat misleading to a programmer when viewing the compile listing. That DFHEIBLK is defined in the LINKAGE SECTION and received as the first parameter but is not shown in the LINKAGE SECTION and does not appear on the PROCEDURE DIVISION statement.

Comment: I'm not sure they made the best decisions with what would appear in the output compared to how it appears with the pre-processor. However, now, all that can be done is a Request For Enhancement (or more than one). You won't be the only person who sees it as an issue, people get to vote for the RFEs, IBM evaluates them against work involved, their strategic views (may not count him), and perceived user-need. I think you'd have a good chance with this, if not already covered by another RFE.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I'll check to see if there is an RFE that addresses the issue and let you know.

Comment: Happened to be at the RFE site, so looked up the other one I saw: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rfe/execute?use_case=viewRfe&CR_ID=93730. It is "under consideration". I think a good time to raise your as well.

Comment: I took your advice Bill, I voted for the RFE you reffered to and also opened one for my issue. You are very welcome to vote for it. number 95165.

Comment: Thanks. I've voted for it, and publicised both on the IBM-MAIN LISTSERV.

Comment: You don't have to let the integrated translator auto-include those for you.  If you explicitly list them, it will not add them again, and I think you can see them in the output.  Of course, I only played with the integrated translator long enough to know that my shop couldn't use it, so YMMV.

Comment: I've been doing this for a few decades and I don't think I've ever seen a programmer explicitly code DFHEIBLK. It's probably better that way cause there's less chance of getting something wrong.